# endless scrolling using wagtail elasticsearch functionality

Tags: elasticsearch, vue.js, wagtail, wagtail-search

I've implemented a webapp using wagtail and vuejs. It heavily relies on the search fuctionalities implemented in wagtail. Is it possible to implement an endless scrolling page using wagtail and its elasticsearch integration? There are references that the elastic backend uses the elastic `scroll` API but I cannot find any documentation on how to actually use it.

Comment: Are you looking for Elasticsearch documentation? Or wagtail documentation?

Comment: I'm looking for wagtail documentation.